# Storage blob delete-batch to delete all blobs excluding two directories with similar names

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, glob, azure-cli

Thanks to the answer by [@Jim Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720027/998196) I've gotten far, but I remain with the following issue. I want to delete all files except those in the folder `data` and `cms`.

Current files

```
  - cms/a2907135_1800x900.jpg
  - cms/c1964f4e_1800x900.jpg
  - css/app.9e1921c7.css
  - css/chunk-vendors.4bdbfeab.css
  - css/pageContent.88886da1.css
  - data/themes.json
  - data/website.json
  - data_old/downloads.json
  - data_old/staff.json
  - data_old/themes.json
  - data_old/website.json
  - img/flags.5fa419a7.png
  - img/star/favicon.ico
  - img/via/favicon.ico
  - img/via/favicon.png
  - img/via/mask-icon.svg
  - img/via/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png
  - img/via/touch-icon-ipad.png
  - img/via/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png
  - img/via/touch-icon-iphone.png
  - index.html
  - js/app.136c0496.js
  - js/app.136c0496.js.map
  - js/chunk-vendors.2dcffb72.js
  - js/chunk-vendors.2dcffb72.js.map
  - js/pageContent.55ebca01.js
  - js/pageContent.55ebca01.js.map
  - js/pageHome.e085832d.js
  - js/pageHome.e085832d.js.map
  - js/pageNotFound.e5d65257.js
  - js/pageNotFound.e5d65257.js.map
  - robots.txt
```

Using `az storage blob delete-batch` to delete the files with the pattern `--pattern '[!data&&!cms]*'` results in the following files to delete

```
  - img/flags.5fa419a7.png
  - img/star/favicon.ico
  - img/via/favicon.ico
  - img/via/favicon.png
  - img/via/mask-icon.svg
  - img/via/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png
  - img/via/touch-icon-ipad.png
  - img/via/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png
  - img/via/touch-icon-iphone.png
  - index.html
  - js/app.136c0496.js
  - js/app.136c0496.js.map
  - js/chunk-vendors.2dcffb72.js
  - js/chunk-vendors.2dcffb72.js.map
  - js/pageContent.55ebca01.js
  - js/pageContent.55ebca01.js.map
  - js/pageHome.e085832d.js
  - js/pageHome.e085832d.js.map
  - js/pageNotFound.e5d65257.js
  - js/pageNotFound.e5d65257.js.map
  - robots.txt
```

The folder `data_old` and `css` are not deleted. This is probably because of the `[]` used (the normally glob as or) so `data_old` and `css` are matched. But how can I delete them as well? I've tried `--pattern '(!data&&!cms)*'` and `--pattern '!data&&!cms*'` without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be a hard task to do for [`az storage blob delete-batch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch). The supported patterns are limited to `'*'`, `'?'`, `'[seq]'`, and `'[!seq]'`, which are found at Pythons [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fnmatch.html) module, and might not be enough for your usecase.

Instead, you could write an [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-3.6.1) script to do this for you. There are alot of handy [Az.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-3.6.1#storage) management cmdlets you can use to do this task.

**Demo:**

```
$storageAccountName = "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME"
$storageAccountKey = "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"

$container = "web"
$foldersToKeep = "data", "cms"

$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container $container -Blob * | ForEach-Object {
    $contents = $_.Name.Split("/")
    if ($contents.Length -gt 1 -and $contents[0] -notin $foldersToKeep) {
        Write-Host "Deleting $($_.Name)"
        Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $container -Blob $_.Name -Context $storageContext
    }
}
```

Which you can also wrap into a function for reusability:

```
function Remove-AzureBlobsFromFolders {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Container,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string[]]$ExcludeFolders,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$StorageAccountName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$StorageAccountKey
    )

    $storageContext = New-AzStorageContext `
        -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
        -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

    Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container $Container -Blob * | ForEach-Object {
        $contents = $_.Name.Split("/")
        if ($contents.Length -gt 1 -and $contents[0] -notin $ExcludeFolders) {
            Write-Host "Deleting $($_.Name)"
            Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $Container -Blob $_.Name -Context $storageContext
        }
    }
}

Remove-AzureBlobsFromFolders `
    -Container "web" `
    -ExcludeFolders "data", "cms" `
    -StorageAccountName "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME" `
    -StorageAccountKey "STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY"
```